# k-sum in weighted DAG

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a known algorithm that solves the following problem:
Given a directed acyclic graph $G$ with weights on the edges, all nodes have a **blue** color. We seek to color with **red** every path $P$ with $K$ edges such that the sum of weights of this path is greater than a threshold (T)

We tried to use dynamic programming to solve this, P(s,t,K) is all the paths from s to t with K length, then we moved to k=1 until k=K and this way we find all paths between all nodes with exactly K length. then we go over these paths and check which paths sum exceed the threshold T and we color it with red. this algorithm is exponential. is there a better one?

Comment: What does the nodes being **blue** have to do with anything?

Comment: @suer2660770 If you give some idea of what you have tried you will probably get many more and much better responses

Comment: The coloring is on the nodes, we would like to distinguish between the **blue** nodes and **red** node after the coloring - **red** nodes are inside "hot path" while **blue** nodes are inside "cold paths"

Comment: We tried to use dynamic programming to solve this, P(s,t,K) is all the paths from s to t with K length, then we moved to k=1 until k=K and this way we find all paths between all nodes with exactly K length. then we go over these paths and check which paths sum exceed the threshold T and we color it with red. this algorithm is exponential. is there a better one?

Comment: So I'm still a little unclear as to what the goal is? Is it to find the vertices with the property that none lie on any path with $K$ edges and theshold $\geq T$, or do you want to actually find all of those paths?

Comment: the goal is to find the vertices (blue) with the property that none lie on any path with K edges and threshold ≥T while the others will be marked with red. no need to find the actual paths.